# How to change date format in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

I just want to change date format on my website. Actually currently I am getting result like this: (Thu Mar 14 2013) and I want to change it like this: (2013-03-14)
Please help

My Code is:
**On HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="date_from" name="date_from" >

var picker = new Pikaday(
{
    field: document.getElementById('date_from'),
    firstDay: 1,
    yearRange: [2013,2015],

});

var picker = new Pikaday(
{
    field: document.getElementById('date_to'),
    firstDay: 1,
    yearRange: [2013,2015],

});
```

**End HTML**

**Include File (pikaday.js)**

```
(function(window, document, undefined)
{
'use strict';

/**
 * feature detection and helper functions
 */
var hasMoment = typeof window.moment === 'function',

hasEventListeners = !!window.addEventListener,

sto = window.setTimeout,

addEvent = function(el, e, callback, capture)
{
    if (hasEventListeners) {
        el.addEventListener(e, callback, !!capture);
    } else {
        el.attachEvent('on' + e, callback);
    }
},

removeEvent = function(el, e, callback, capture)
{
    if (hasEventListeners) {
        el.removeEventListener(e, callback, !!capture);
    } else {
        el.detachEvent('on' + e, callback);
    }
},

fireEvent = function(el, eventName, data)
{
    var ev;

    if (document.createEvent) {
        ev = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        ev.initEvent(eventName, true, false);
        ev = extend(ev, data);
        el.dispatchEvent(ev);
    } else if (document.createEventObject) {
        ev = document.createEventObject();
        ev = extend(ev, data);
        el.fireEvent('on' + eventName, ev);
    }
},

trim = function(str)
{
    return str.trim ? str.trim() : str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
},

hasClass = function(el, cn)
{
    return (' ' + el.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cn + ' ') !== -1;
},

addClass = function(el, cn)
{
    if (!hasClass(el, cn)) {
        el.className = (el.className === '') ? cn : el.className + ' ' + cn;
    }
},

removeClass = function(el, cn)
{
    el.className = trim((' ' + el.className + ' ').replace(' ' + cn + ' ', ' '));
},

isArray = function(obj)
{
    return (/Array/).test(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj));
},

isDate = function(obj)
{
    return (/Date/).test(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)) && !isNaN(obj.getTime());
},

isLeapYear = function(year)
{
    // solution by Matti Virkkunen: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4881951
    return year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 !== 0 || year % 400 === 0;
},

getDaysInMonth = function(year, month)
{
    return [31, isLeapYear(year) ? 29 : 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31][month];
},

setToStartOfDay = function(date)
{
    if (isDate(date)) date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
},

compareDates = function(a,b)
{
    // weak date comparison (use setToStartOfDay(date) to ensure correct result)
    return a.getTime() === b.getTime();
},

extend = function(to, from, overwrite)
{
    var prop, hasProp;
    for (prop in from) {
        hasProp = to[prop] !== undefined;
        if (hasProp && typeof from[prop] === 'object' && from[prop].nodeName === undefined) {
            if (isDate(from[prop])) {
                if (overwrite) {
                    to[prop] = new Date(from[prop].getTime());
                }
            }
            else if (isArray(from[prop])) {
                if (overwrite) {
                    to[prop] = from[prop].slice(0);
                }
            } else {
                to[prop] = extend({}, from[prop], overwrite);
            }
        } else if (overwrite || !hasProp) {
            to[prop] = from[prop];
        }
    }
    return to;
},


/**
 * defaults and localisation
 */
defaults = {

    // bind the picker to a form field
    field: null,

    // automatically show/hide the picker on `field` focus (default `true` if `field` is set)
    bound: undefined,

    // the default output format for `.toString()` and `field` value
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',

    // the initial date to view when first opened
    defaultDate: null,

    // make the `defaultDate` the initial selected value
    setDefaultDate: false,

    // first day of week (0: Sunday, 1: Monday etc)
    firstDay: 0,

    // the minimum/earliest date that can be selected
    minDate: null,
    // the maximum/latest date that can be selected
    maxDate: null,

    // number of years either side, or array of upper/lower range
    yearRange: 10,

    // used internally (don't config outside)
    minYear: 0,
    maxYear: 9999,
    minMonth: undefined,
    maxMonth: undefined,


    isRTL: false,

    // how many months are visible (not implemented yet)
    numberOfMonths: 1,

    // internationalization
    i18n: {
        previousMonth : 'Previous Month',
        nextMonth     : 'Next Month',
        months        : ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'],
        weekdays      : ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'],
        weekdaysShort : ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat']
    },

    // callback function
    onSelect: null,
    onOpen: null,
    onClose: null,
    onDraw: null
},


/**
 * templating functions to abstract HTML rendering
 */
renderDayName = function(opts, day, abbr)
{
    day += opts.firstDay;
    while (day >= 7) {
        day -= 7;
    }
    return abbr ? opts.i18n.weekdaysShort[day] : opts.i18n.weekdays[day];
},

renderDay = function(i, isSelected, isToday, isDisabled, isEmpty)
{
    if (isEmpty) {
        return '<td class="is-empty"></td>';
    }
    var arr = [];
    if (isDisabled) {
        arr.push('is-disabled');
    }
    if (isToday) {
        arr.push('is-today');
    }
    if (isSelected) {
        arr.push('is-selected');
    }
    return '<td data-day="' + i + '" class="' + arr.join(' ') + '"><button class="pika-button" type="button">' + i + '</button>' + '</td>';
},

renderRow = function(days, isRTL)
{
    return '<tr>' + (isRTL ? days.reverse() : days).join('') + '</tr>';
},

renderBody = function(rows)
{
    return '<tbody>' + rows.join('') + '</tbody>';
},

renderHead = function(opts)
{
    var i, arr = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        arr.push('<th scope="col"><abbr title="' + renderDayName(opts, i) + '">' + renderDayName(opts, i, true) + '</abbr></th>');
    }
    return '<thead>' + (opts.isRTL ? arr.reverse() : arr).join('') + '</thead>';
},

renderTitle = function(instance)
{
    var i, j, arr,
        opts = instance._o,
        month = instance._m,
        year  = instance._y,
        isMinYear = year === opts.minYear,
        isMaxYear = year === opts.maxYear,
        html = '<div class="pika-title">',
        prev = true,
        next = true;

    for (arr = [], i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        arr.push('<option value="' + i + '"' +
            (i === month ? ' selected': '') +
            ((isMinYear && i < opts.minMonth) || (isMaxYear && i > opts.maxMonth) ? 'disabled' : '') + '>' +
            opts.i18n.months[i] + '</option>');
    }
    html += '<div class="pika-label">' + opts.i18n.months[month] + '<select class="pika-select pika-select-month">' + arr.join('') + '</select></div>';

    if (isArray(opts.yearRange)) {
        i = opts.yearRange[0];
        j = opts.yearRange[1] + 1;
    } else {
        i = year - opts.yearRange;
        j = 1 + year + opts.yearRange;
    }

    for (arr = []; i < j && i <= opts.maxYear; i++) {
        if (i >= opts.minYear) {
            arr.push('<option value="' + i + '"' + (i === year ? ' selected': '') + '>' + (i) + '</option>');
        }
    }
    html += '<div class="pika-label">' + year + '<select class="pika-select pika-select-year">' + arr.join('') + '</select></div>';

    if (isMinYear && (month === 0 || opts.minMonth >= month)) {
        prev = false;
    }

    if (isMaxYear && (month === 11 || opts.maxMonth <= month)) {
        next = false;
    }

    html += '<button class="pika-prev' + (prev ? '' : ' is-disabled') + '" type="button">' + opts.i18n.previousMonth + '</button>';
    html += '<button class="pika-next' + (next ? '' : ' is-disabled') + '" type="button">' + opts.i18n.nextMonth + '</button>';

    return html += '</div>';
},

renderTable = function(opts, data)
{
    return '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="pika-table">' + renderHead(opts) + renderBody(data) + '</table>';
};


/**
 * Pikaday constructor
 */
window.Pikaday = function(options)
{
    var self = this,
        opts = self.config(options);

    self._onMouseDown = function(e)
    {
        if (!self._v) {
            return;
        }
        e = e || window.event;
        var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
        if (!target) {
            return;
        }

        if (!hasClass(target, 'is-disabled')) {
            if (hasClass(target, 'pika-button') && !hasClass(target, 'is-empty')) {
                self.setDate(new Date(self._y, self._m, parseInt(target.innerHTML, 10)));
                if (opts.bound) {
                    sto(function() {
                        self.hide();
                    }, 100);
                }
                return;
            }
            else if (hasClass(target, 'pika-prev')) {
                self.prevMonth();
            }
            else if (hasClass(target, 'pika-next')) {
                self.nextMonth();
            }
        }
        if (!hasClass(target, 'pika-select')) {
            if (e.preventDefault) {
                e.preventDefault();
            } else {
                e.returnValue = false;
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            self._c = true;
        }
    };

    self._onChange = function(e)
    {
        e = e || window.event;
        var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
        if (!target) {
            return;
        }
        if (hasClass(target, 'pika-select-month')) {
            self.gotoMonth(target.value);
        }
        else if (hasClass(target, 'pika-select-year')) {
            self.gotoYear(target.value);
        }
    };

    self._onInputChange = function(e)
    {
        var date;

        if (e.firedBy === self) {
            return;
        }
        if (hasMoment) {
            date = window.moment(opts.field.value, opts.format);
            date = date ? date.toDate() : null;
        }
        else {
            date = new Date(Date.parse(opts.field.value));
        }
        self.setDate(isDate(date) ? date : null);
        if (!self._v) {
            self.show();
        }
    };

    self._onInputFocus = function()
    {
        self.show();
    };

    self._onInputClick = function()
    {
        self.show();
    };

    self._onInputBlur = function()
    {
        if (!self._c) {
            self._b = sto(function() {
                self.hide();
            }, 50);
        }
        self._c = false;
    };

    self._onClick = function(e)
    {
        e = e || window.event;
        var target = e.target || e.srcElement,
            pEl = target;
        if (!target) {
            return;
        }
        if (!hasEventListeners && hasClass(target, 'pika-select')) {
            if (!target.onchange) {
                target.setAttribute('onchange', 'return;');
                addEvent(target, 'change', self._onChange);
            }
        }
        do {
            if (hasClass(pEl, 'pika-single')) {
                return;
            }
        }
        while ((pEl = pEl.parentNode));
        if (self._v && target !== opts.field) {
            self.hide();
        }
    };

    self.el = document.createElement('div');
    self.el.className = 'pika-single' + (opts.isRTL ? ' is-rtl' : '');

    addEvent(self.el, 'mousedown', self._onMouseDown, true);
    addEvent(self.el, 'change', self._onChange);

    if (opts.field) {
        if (opts.bound) {
            document.body.appendChild(self.el);
        } else {
            opts.field.parentNode.insertBefore(self.el, opts.field.nextSibling);
        }
        addEvent(opts.field, 'change', self._onInputChange);

        if (!opts.defaultDate) {
            if (hasMoment && opts.field.value) {
                opts.defaultDate = window.moment(opts.field.value, opts.format).toDate();
            } else {
                opts.defaultDate = new Date(Date.parse(opts.field.value));
            }
            opts.setDefaultDate = true;
        }
    }

    var defDate = opts.defaultDate;

    if (isDate(defDate)) {
        if (opts.setDefaultDate) {
            self.setDate(defDate, true);
        } else {
            self.gotoDate(defDate);
        }
    } else {
        self.gotoDate(new Date());
    }

    if (opts.bound) {
        this.hide();
        self.el.className += ' is-bound';
        addEvent(opts.field, 'click', self._onInputClick);
        addEvent(opts.field, 'focus', self._onInputFocus);
        addEvent(opts.field, 'blur', self._onInputBlur);
    } else {
        this.show();
    }

};


/**
 * public Pikaday API
 */
window.Pikaday.prototype = {


    /**
     * configure functionality
     */
    config: function(options)
    {
        if (!this._o) {
            this._o = extend({}, defaults, true);
        }

        var opts = extend(this._o, options, true);

        opts.isRTL = !!opts.isRTL;

        opts.field = (opts.field && opts.field.nodeName) ? opts.field : null;

        opts.bound = !!(opts.bound !== undefined ? opts.field && opts.bound : opts.field);

        var nom = parseInt(opts.numberOfMonths, 10) || 1;
        opts.numberOfMonths = nom > 4 ? 4 : nom;

        if (!isDate(opts.minDate)) {
            opts.minDate = false;
        }
        if (!isDate(opts.maxDate)) {
            opts.maxDate = false;
        }
        if ((opts.minDate && opts.maxDate) && opts.maxDate < opts.minDate) {
            opts.maxDate = opts.minDate = false;
        }
        if (opts.minDate) {
            setToStartOfDay(opts.minDate);
            opts.minYear  = opts.minDate.getFullYear();
            opts.minMonth = opts.minDate.getMonth();
        }
        if (opts.maxDate) {
            setToStartOfDay(opts.maxDate);
            opts.maxYear  = opts.maxDate.getFullYear();
            opts.maxMonth = opts.maxDate.getMonth();
        }

        if (isArray(opts.yearRange)) {
            var fallback = new Date().getFullYear() - 10;
            opts.yearRange[0] = parseInt(opts.yearRange[0], 10) || fallback;
            opts.yearRange[1] = parseInt(opts.yearRange[1], 10) || fallback;
        } else {
            opts.yearRange = Math.abs(parseInt(opts.yearRange, 10)) || defaults.yearRange;
            if (opts.yearRange > 100) {
                opts.yearRange = 100;
            }
        }

        return opts;
    },

    /**
     * return a formatted string of the current selection (using Moment.js if available)
     */
    toString: function(format)
    {
        return !isDate(this._d) ? '' : hasMoment ? window.moment(this._d).format(format || this._o.format) : this._d.toDateString();
    },

    /**
     * return a Moment.js object of the current selection (if available)
     */
    getMoment: function()
    {
        return hasMoment ? window.moment(this._d) : null;
    },

    /**
     * set the current selection from a Moment.js object (if available)
     */
    setMoment: function(date)
    {
        if (hasMoment && window.moment.isMoment(date)) {
            this.setDate(date.toDate());
        }
    },

    /**
     * return a Date object of the current selection
     */
    getDate: function()
    {
        return isDate(this._d) ? new Date(this._d.getTime()) : null;
    },

    /**
     * set the current selection
     */
    setDate: function(date, preventOnSelect)
    {
        if (!date) {
            this._d = null;
            return this.draw();
        }
        if (typeof date === 'string') {
            date = new Date(Date.parse(date));
        }
        if (!isDate(date)) {
            return;
        }

        var min = this._o.minDate,
            max = this._o.maxDate;

        if (isDate(min) && date < min) {
            date = min;
        } else if (isDate(max) && date > max) {
            date = max;
        }

        this._d = new Date(date.getTime());
        setToStartOfDay(this._d);
        this.gotoDate(this._d);

        if (this._o.field) {
            this._o.field.value = this.toString();
            fireEvent(this._o.field, 'change', { firedBy: this });
        }
        if (!preventOnSelect && typeof this._o.onSelect === 'function') {
            this._o.onSelect.call(this, this.getDate());
        }
    },

    /**
     * change view to a specific date
     */
    gotoDate: function(date)
    {
        if (!isDate(date)) {
            return;
        }
        this._y = date.getFullYear();
        this._m = date.getMonth();
        this.draw();
    },

    gotoToday: function()
    {
        this.gotoDate(new Date());
    },

    /**
     * change view to a specific month (zero-index, e.g. 0: January)
     */
    gotoMonth: function(month)
    {
        if (!isNaN( (month = parseInt(month, 10)) )) {
            this._m = month < 0 ? 0 : month > 11 ? 11 : month;
            this.draw();
        }
    },

    nextMonth: function()
    {
        if (++this._m > 11) {
            this._m = 0;
            this._y++;
        }
        this.draw();
    },

    prevMonth: function()
    {
        if (--this._m < 0) {
            this._m = 11;
            this._y--;
        }
        this.draw();
    },

    /**
     * change view to a specific full year (e.g. "2012")
     */
    gotoYear: function(year)
    {
        if (!isNaN(year)) {
            this._y = parseInt(year, 10);
            this.draw();
        }
    },

    /**
     * refresh the HTML
     */
    draw: function(force)
    {
        if (!this._v && !force) {
            return;
        }
        var opts = this._o,
            minYear = opts.minYear,
            maxYear = opts.maxYear,
            minMonth = opts.minMonth,
            maxMonth = opts.maxMonth;

        if (this._y <= minYear) {
            this._y = minYear;
            if (!isNaN(minMonth) && this._m < minMonth) {
                this._m = minMonth;
            }
        }
        if (this._y >= maxYear) {
            this._y = maxYear;
            if (!isNaN(maxMonth) && this._m > maxMonth) {
                this._m = maxMonth;
            }
        }

        this.el.innerHTML = renderTitle(this) + this.render(this._y, this._m);

        if (opts.bound) {
            var pEl  = opts.field,
                left = pEl.offsetLeft,
                top  = pEl.offsetTop + pEl.offsetHeight;
            while((pEl = pEl.offsetParent)) {
                left += pEl.offsetLeft;
                top  += pEl.offsetTop;
            }
            this.el.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;left:' + left + 'px;top:' + top + 'px;';
            sto(function() {
                opts.field.focus();
            }, 1);
        }

        if (typeof this._o.onDraw === 'function') {
            var self = this;
            sto(function() {
                self._o.onDraw.call(self);
            }, 0);
        }
    },

    /**
     * render HTML for a particular month
     */
    render: function(year, month)
    {
        var opts   = this._o,
            now    = new Date(),
            days   = getDaysInMonth(year, month),
            before = new Date(year, month, 1).getDay(),
            data   = [],
            row    = [];
        setToStartOfDay(now);
        if (opts.firstDay > 0) {
            before -= opts.firstDay;
            if (before < 0) {
                before += 7;
            }
        }
        var cells = days + before,
            after = cells;
        while(after > 7) {
            after -= 7;
        }
        cells += 7 - after;
        for (var i = 0, r = 0; i < cells; i++)
        {
            var day = new Date(year, month, 1 + (i - before)),
                isDisabled = (opts.minDate && day < opts.minDate) || (opts.maxDate && day > opts.maxDate),
                isSelected = isDate(this._d) ? compareDates(day, this._d) : false,
                isToday = compareDates(day, now),
                isEmpty = i < before || i >= (days + before);

            row.push(renderDay(1 + (i - before), isSelected, isToday, isDisabled, isEmpty));

            if (++r === 7) {
                data.push(renderRow(row, opts.isRTL));
                row = [];
                r = 0;
            }
        }
        return renderTable(opts, data);
    },

    isVisible: function()
    {
        return this._v;
    },

    show: function()
    {
        if (!this._v) {
            if (this._o.bound) {
                addEvent(document, 'click', this._onClick);
            }
            removeClass(this.el, 'is-hidden');
            this._v = true;
            this.draw();
            if (typeof this._o.onOpen === 'function') {
                this._o.onOpen.call(this);
            }
        }
    },

    hide: function()
    {
        var v = this._v;
        if (v !== false) {
            if (this._o.bound) {
                removeEvent(document, 'click', this._onClick);
            }
            this.el.style.cssText = '';
            addClass(this.el, 'is-hidden');
            this._v = false;
            if (v !== undefined && typeof this._o.onClose === 'function') {
                this._o.onClose.call(this);
            }
        }
    },

    /**
     * GAME OVER
     */
    destroy: function()
    {
        this.hide();
        removeEvent(this.el, 'mousedown', this._onMouseDown, true);
        removeEvent(this.el, 'change', this._onChange);
        if (this._o.field) {
            removeEvent(this._o.field, 'change', this._onInputChange);
            if (this._o.bound) {
                removeEvent(this._o.field, 'click', this._onInputClick);
                removeEvent(this._o.field, 'focus', this._onInputFocus);
                removeEvent(this._o.field, 'blur', this._onInputBlur);
            }
        }
        if (this.el.parentNode) {
            this.el.parentNode.removeChild(this.el);
        }
    }

};

})(window, window.document);
```

Answer (score 1):

i have forced the format of the data in this way (date format is dd-MM-YYYY):

```
            // formatto la data come voglio...
            Pikaday.prototype.toString = function () {
                return ('0' + this._d.getDate()).slice(-2) + "-" + ('0' + (this._d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + this._d.getFullYear();
            };

            // il parse con le date all'italiana... 
            Date.parse = function (sDateString) {
                var parts = sDateString.split("-");
                return (new Date(parseInt(parts[2], 10), parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1, parseInt(parts[0], 10)));
            }
```

First function rewrite the Pikaday toString function.
Second function rewrite the javascript parse function (that parse the data in mm-dd-yyyy).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [Pikaday has a format option](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday#usage) when coupled with [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/):

```
<script src="moment.js"></script>
<script src="pikaday.js"></script>

<script>

  var picker = new Pikaday(
  {
      ...
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
      ...
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but I already tried it but its not working for me :( any other way please ?

Comment: Did you load moment.js before pikaday.js?

Comment: Ohh great now its working I just put moment.js before pikaday.js Thank you soooooooooo much :)

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to accept the answer to help others identify the solution if they experience the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Pikaday Demo.](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday)
Like you can see there, pikaday has a format option. Only add
`format:'YYYY-MM-DD'` to the object.

And load moment.js before the pikaday.js ..